# Can a trefoil knot be stretched to look like a triangle with three knots at the vertices?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, geometric-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

Can a trefoil knot be stretched to look like a triangle with three knots at the vertices, like in the right side of the image below, or is that transformation impossible to happen? If possible, what is the nature of the crossings that has to occur at the three corners of the triangle like figure on the right hand side?
[image]

Comment: The trefoil knot is a prime knot, i.e. it cannot be split to 3 (or any number $\geq2$) successive knots

Comment: @user8268. Can you extend on your statement and infer on if the right hand image is possible or not? Thanks again. Am not a topologist!

Comment: see e.g. wikipedia for the definition of prime knots. Trefoil being prime implies that the right hand image is impossible (provided the knots at at least 2 of the 3 vertices of the triangle are nontrivial :) [I'm not a topologist either]

Comment: Thanks! I'd need a microscope to zoom if these vertices are non-trivial :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

$$\boldsymbol{\operatorname{Figure:}}  \text{ The Stretchfoil}$$

Comment: Okay, I'm being a bit flippant here.  But is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes! Indeed ....

Comment: Good! Then the answer to the question you've posted is *yes*. A knot type is defined up to "ambient isotopy", which basically means continuously pushing or pulling the knot any which way, as long as you don't break the string by tearing it open or passing part of one strand through another.

Comment: This made me burst out laughing.